# Storing the API endpoints in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, constants, endpoint

I am currently trying to create an API-wrapper. For that, I connect to the endpoint (for example https://host.example.com/api/accounts/open) with the request module. Since there are a bunch of endpoints, I need a way to sort them. Currently I have a constants file, where most of the endpoints are created like this:

```
HOST = 'https://wallet.shiftnrg.org'
START = ''.join([HOST, '/api'])

ACCOUNTS = ''.join([START, '/accounts'])
ACCOUNTS_OPEN = ''.join([ACCOUNTS, '/open'])
...
LOADER = ''.join([START, '/loader'])
LOADER_GET_STATUS = ''.join([LOADER, '/status'])
```

And I access them like this:

```
def accounts_get_balance(address):
    payload = {'address': address}
    response = requests.get(constants.ACCOUNTS_GET_BALANCE,
                        params=payload,
                        timeout=constants.TIMEOUT
)
```

While this is working, I was wondering if there is a more efficient, pythonic way of doing this, since I am just a beginner.

Comment: If your code work then SO is not the right place - you may want to repost this on codereview instead.

Comment: Do I understand you want to do something about the redundancy of having a function called `accounts_get_balance` that calls `get` with the constant `ACCOUNTS_GET_BALANCE` and passes it a dict with the key `"address"` that has the value of the function parameter `address`?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Alright, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just FWIW: there are already a quite a couple python clients for  various  rest apis, you may want to check how they are implemented.